# How to Bind Values from List in BarChart

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, bar-chart

I have an application which is check the incoming Mails on the Server and refresh a List with X-Values in it. Now I want to Plot the incoming Mail count in a Live Chart. I use http://lvcharts.net for this.

I have two classes a Mail Object with the Count and a `TimeStamp`  in it and a List Class with all Mail Objects in it.

Here is my sample(pseudo) XAMl code:

```
<liveCharts:BarChart Name="MailChart" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <liveCharts:BarChart.Series>
        <liveCharts:BarSeries Title="Mails" Values= "{Binding MailCountList.Count}"></liveCharts:BarSeries>
    ......        
    ......
    <liveCharts:BarChart.AxisY>
        <liveCharts:Axis Title="Time" Labels="{Binding MailCountList.Timestamp}">
    ......
```

The Objects are in a normal List with automatically Refesh I use MVVM.

**My Question is:**

How can I bind a List to a XAML Value Series ?

Comment: Change your `List<T>` to an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used an ObservableCollection to view the Content and a normal list to fill sort etc. the Xaml Code Looks Like:

```
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TableList}" Grid.Row="0">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Group" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Group}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="85" Header="Version" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Version}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

The Source of the ListView is in the ItemSource and to Display Multiple Rows I use GridViewColumn with Binding to the Object Values from the List in "DisplayMemberBinding"